# Solution for N:N relationship without permission to create auxiliary table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

i was interviewed with a question, and i am not sure, if the interviewer was trying to confuse me or he was serious.

Question was something, that we have a `Student` table:

```
Student
ID, Name
```

and a `Course` table:

```
Course
ID, Name
```

Now what i want is to map course with student in N-N relationship.

I created a new table `StudentCourseRelationship`

```
 StudentCourseRelationShip
 ID    StudentID    CourseID
```

He replied we don't have privileges to create new table, i asked can we add a new column, he said yes.

So i replied him, that this is not a recommended way, but you can add a column in either `Course` or `Student` table and put comma separated values in it.

like

```
Student 
ID  Name
1   abc
2   def
3   ghi
4   hij
5   jkl

Course 
ID  Name      StudentIDs
 1  English   1,3,4
 2  Maths     3,5
 3  Geography 1,2,4
```

He said fine, tell me third solution.
I got stuck there, he didn't tell me the third solution, but i am curious, if any third solution exists, because at the end when he said do you want to ask something, i said yes, i would like to know the third solution, and he was like, there is a third solution, go and search for it.

Comment: You could invent any number of 'artifical' solutions, e.g. store the relationships in a text file outside the database. And having permission to add columns but not tables makes little sense. I don't think there's much point in trying to find answers to questions that have unreasonable and artificial limitations, especially interview questions.

Comment: You can create a temporary table. Why is this tagged `mysql` and `sql-server`? You ***do not*** store multiple values in one column.

Comment: Some DBMSes also support arrays or even nested tables. You could have also created another schema (depending on DBMS) in which you _do_ have privileges to create a table. If all else fails, you could even create a completely new database (possibly on another machine or even a different DBMS) and maintain the referential integrity in code. All this is pretty much beside the point, of course - I think you should have pressed the interviewer to provide the rationale for the permission restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, a solution could be that you store a list in both tables (so as to make retrieval faster in both directions).

Thinking outside the box, I would say that asking the DBA to kindly create the table for you is also a solution :o)

Comment: It's quite likely that asking the DBA was the answer he was looking for. Phrased in another way, this question is asking whether you'd rather ask for support or do a hackjob.

Answer (score 0):

You can always drop the uniqueness constraint of the `ID` column in either table, say, in the `Course` table. Then, the `Course` table becomes what you have called the `StudentCourseRelationship` table. Of course this breaks normalization, but still it's less "hacky" than adding a comma-separated `ID` column.

```
Course
ID Name    StudentID
 1 English 1
 1 English 3
 1 English 4
 2 Maths   3
 ...
```

I agree that the "ask the DBA" solution is perhaps the neatest. You might have asked how important it is to the interviewer to keep the database normalized...

Comment: Yeah definitely, i proposed him this solution but he refused as rows are repeated. and then i changed it to the solution which i have provided in the question that add a column in course table for student ids, and put student ids as comma seperated

Comment: @QasimJavaidKhan: If you had noted that in your question, this would have saved time.